# Change dynamic style in angular textbox

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this textbox

```html
<input type="text" [ngStyle]="(show_div===true) ? {'border-color':'red','color':'red'} : {'border-color': 'green','color':'green'}" [(ngModel)]="values[i]"/>
```

If `show_div` variable is true i want to make `{'border-color':'red','color':'red'}` if it is false then i have to make it `{'border-color': 'green','color':'green'}` but initially i want to make textbox and text color black, green and red is working but initially also the text are green but that should be black.

Any solution Thanks

Comment: When do you expect `show_div` to have value different than true/false? Is it from subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to show the corresponding ts code to get a more accurate response. Based on the information you have provided, I would assume that the initial of `show_div` is `undefined`. If that is the case, then you need to add another condition in your ternary as follows.

```html
<input  type="text" [ngStyle]="(show_div===true) ? {'border-color':'red','color':'red'} : show_div === undefined ? {'border-color': 'black','color':'black'} : {'border-color': 'green','color':'green'}" [(ngModel)]="values[i]"/>
```

This is really making your html very verbose and difficult to read though. Personally, I would put these styles in your styles file and associate them with a class. I would then switch the classes dynamically in your component instead of the styles.

Comment: Thanks `show_div` is initially false

Comment: |I tried this but getting this error `NG5002: Parser Error: Conditional expression (show_div===true) ? {'border-color':'red','color':'red'}  requires all 3 expressions at column 61 in`

Comment: @user3653474 I had a typo that I fixed. It should work now.